# Coupled ODEs with boundary conditions - DSolve Error

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, variable-definitions

I'm relatively new to mathematica and I can't find the error here. I suspect it has something to do with the fact that vx, vy, vz aren't blue on my mathematica - as in, they already have some assigned values. But I don't know how that would have happened. I get the error "Supplied equations are not differential equations of the given functions."

Code:

```
DSolve[{
  vx'[t] == 
    (fx*c^2 - vx[t]*(fx*vx[t] + fy*vy[t] + fz*vz[t]) ) /
      (m*(c^2*Sqrt[1 - (vx[t]^2 + vy[t]^2 + vz[t]^2)/c^2] + vx[t]^2 + vy[t]^2 + vz[t]^2)), 
  vy'[t] == 
    (fy*c^2 - vy[t]*(fx*vx[t] + fy*vy[t] + fz*vz[t])) /
       (m*(c^2*Sqrt[1 - (vx[t]^2 + vy[t]^2 + vz[t]^2)/c^2] + vx[t]^2 + vy[t]^2 + vz[t]^2)), 
  vz'[t] == 
    (fz*c^2 - vz[t]*(fx*vx[t] + fy*vy[t] + fz*vz[t])) / 
      (m*(c^2*Sqrt[1 - (vx[t]^2 + vy[t]^2 + vz[t]^2)/c^2] + vx[t]^2 + vy[t]^2 + vz[t]^2)),  
  vx[0] == 1, vy[0] == 1, vz[0] == 1}, {vx, vy, vz},t]
```

Comment: You can either clear all symbols with eg `ClearAll[vx,vy]` etc or quit the kernel with `Quit`. In any case if you do that `DSolve` doesn't return a solution.

Comment: To clarify acl's comment, after clearing these symbols (or restarting the kernel), `DSolve` will not give any errors, but it will still not be able to solve the system.  You can use `NDSolve` to get a numerical solution when getting an analytic solution is not possible.

Comment: So is the error just because the equation doesn't have an analytic solution, or is there something wrong with my syntax?

Comment: Weird. I just opened the .nb again, ran it again without any changes, and got no error this time. What could have caused that??